# Configuration SonataMediaBundle from the Symfony2 framework

Tags: symfony, configuration, media

I finished configuring `SonataMediaBundle` successfully then the page

> /formation/web/app_dev.php/admin/dashboard

is displayed.

But when I click "list" (menu Media), I get this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Parameter "id" for route "admin_sonata_media_media_edit" must match
>   "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in
>   SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list_custom.html.twig at line 17.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is based on this known issue:
[Sonata type model - hide/delete the "create" button · Issue #530 · sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/issues/330)

It is recommended to update to Doctrine **2.4**